# first run of any page gives a gzip file

Tags: symfony, browser-cache, google-cloud-platform

My symfony project is hosted in google compute instance (ubuntu 15.10 on f1-micro machine (1 vCPU, 0.6 GB memory)). The first run of each page return a gzip file as it is shown in the image [image]

A reload of the page solves the problem.

Any idea to solve this issue?

Thanks

---

### Updates:

this could be due to a proxy? (FYI, this happens only when I am connecting behind a proxy! At home, there is not proxy and no gzip file is displayed)

How is it possible this problem if is really due to the proxy???

### Updates 2:

I used this time IE behind a proxy and the pages are displayed correctly. This is strange: google chrome retunrs in the first run a gzip page & IE returns in the first run the correct page.

Meanwhile, I have noticed 3 more things:

1. **Behind a proxy:** The 2nd, 3rd, ... run are returning correct pages. So, could it be a problem related to the cache?
2. **Behind a proxy:** Pages with forms are always displayed as gzip file in google chrome & in IE, pages are displyed correctly.
3. **Without proxy (at home)** Pages are displayed correctly in all browsers

Comment: this could be due to a proxy? (FYI, this happens only when I am connecting behind a proxy! At home, there is not proxy and no gzip file is displayed)

Comment: Then you proxy destroy your header and the browser can't resolve that its gzip and mentioned that its txt and print them.

Comment: Is there any idea to overcome the proxy? You know, a good website is supposed to overcome proxies...

Comment: How do you explain that only the 1st run is displayed as gzip text and a refresh of the page solve the problem?

Comment: @Stony I have updated my question again. Do you have any comment? Thanks.

Comment: That sounds like a proxy problem. That your proxy don't cache it correctly and remove the gzip header.

Comment: In this case, why the IE is able to return the correct page? Could it be a needed update of google chrome *(by the way I am not the admin of my desktop at office)* ?

Comment: @Stony in my opinion, the problem is coming from `google chrome`...